# box authentication using webdav ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, webdav, box, net-http

I am trying to authenticate box webdav using ruby net/dav

```
require 'net/dav'
url = 'https://dav.box.com/dav/<my_folder_name'
user = 'my_mail_id'
pass = 'my_password'
dav = Net::DAV.new(url, :curl => false)
dav.verify_server = false
dav.credentials(user, pass)
dav.mkdir('/hello')
```

But I am getting 403 'forbidden' error.

Comment: I fixed it myself by, replacing below line in net_dev-0.5.0/lib/net/dav.rb line number 601 path = @uri.merge(path).path  with path = File.join(@uri.to_s, path)